# Webpage stays empty after adding content with javascript div.appendChild(content)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, insert

### Goal:

I am trying to build a simple search form using javascript.

After pressing the submit button, subpages (blogarticles) should be loaded on the page:

[image]

the Prototype can be found here:
[Julian Bechtolds Blogworld - overview](https://julianbechtold.de/de/informatics/overview.html)

### Issue:

**The Webpage does not show any loaded content after pressing "Submit"**
Sometimes I can see added text for a split second, disappearing again. Additionally, all text I typed into the form disappears.
This leads me to the conclusion, that the webpage is beeing updated correctly but then reloads right after script execution, which wipes all added content.

Note the "test" appearing for a split second when I press Submit, then disappearing again
[image]

### Code:

minimum reproducible sample:
html:

```html
<main>
    <form onsubmit="LoadArticles()">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <div id="pages"></div>
</main>
```

javascript:

```
function LoadArticles() {
    var div = document.getElementById('pages');
    var content = document.createTextNode("test");
        div.appendChild(content);
}
```

### Question:

Why is my page reloading after the script is beeing executed?
How can I prevent my page from reloading, which wipes all content added with javascript?

Comment: What is your question...

Comment: updated my code and question. I hope the issue is more apparent now. I am trying to update my page but it is reloaded right after updating it so all changes are lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent the web page from reloading on form submit use `preventDefault()` function. This function basically cancels any event which is cancelable and the default behaviour of that event will not be followed. But that doesn't mean that you can't use forms or get values filled inside the input fields. If you had any `textarea` and you submitted a form, you can always access the value of that textarea inside the called function.

You can read more about this function [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp).

```js
function LoadArticles(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Cancels a cancelable event
    var div = document.getElementById('pages');
    var content = document.createTextNode("test");
    div.appendChild(content);
}
```

```html
<main>
    <form onsubmit="LoadArticles(event)">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <div id="pages"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. Is the issue that the form itself has some event it executes?

Comment: by default, a `submit` button refreshes or reloads a page. All we have to do is just prevent this default behaviour. And we can do that with `preventDefault()` function.

Comment: Good answer. Regarding the supporting link, W3Schools may be better than they used to be, but a few years ago their JavaScript references were notoriously unreliable. So I got in the habit of always using MDN, which is pretty authoritative for almost all things JavaScript. (Anyone interested can see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault for this particular API.)

Comment: thank you for this suggestion as well. I have previously used w3schools for reference but I dont know of how I would have found this...